# The flyby anomaly, rotation, and gyroscopes: help understanding the theoretical connection

Tags: acceleration, gyroscopes

The flyby effect in spaceflight is described in the question [Is the Flyby Anomaly still a thing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23791/12102) It is an very small unexplained acceleration seen in some spacecraft trajectories during flyby maneuvers. While the deviations seem tiny, these things can be both measured and calculated extremely well, and the results have received extensive technical scrutiny. (It's no [Space Unicorn](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27379/12102).)

I've run across the Phys.org article [Gyroscope's unexplained acceleration may be due to modified inertia](https://phys.org/news/2011-07-gyroscope-unexplained-due-inertia.html) which links to McCulloch 2011 [The Tajmar effect from quantised inertia](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/95/39002/meta) as well as Tajmar and Assis 2016 [Influence of Rotation on the Weight of Gyroscopes as an Explanation for Flyby Anomalies](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/asp/jap/2016/00000005/00000002/art00010;jsessionid=8esf9k84l275j.x-ic-live-02). However 1) I won't be able to access these articles for a few days, and 2) things like the Hubble-scale Casimir effect and Unruh radiation are out of my depth anyway.

**Question:** Could someone help me understand to a limited extent how these theories might apply to the measured flyby anomaly, and in an un-opinionated way help put it in context with the rest of current physics understanding?

---

---

What brought me to these is the slide below, which I found [here](https://tu-dresden.de/ing/maschinenwesen/ilr/rfs/forschung/forschungsfelder/raumfahrtantriebe-und-neue-konzepte/breakthrough-propulsion-physics) when reading about the "[Magic Space Unicorns](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/05/nasas-em-drive-is-a-magnetic-wtf-thruster/)." I'm not asking about this slide directly, but it's a potentially helpful collection of "edge" or alternative propulsion theories that may help with context. Click for full size.

[image]

Comment: need help with proper tagging

Comment: Assis is a kook. Cranks in his tribe can be recognized by their belief that Weber's electrodynamics overthrows relativity. Note that the slide includes the text "Weber Electrodynamic."

Comment: The fact that flyby anomalies can't be explained does not imply that they involve new physics. They probably just arise from technical issues such as inaccuracies in changing from one coordinate system to another. There is a history of people making attempts to fit some mathematical rule to the previously observed flyby anomalies, and then what keeps happening is that their rule fails when applied to a later flyby.

Comment: @BenCrowell thanks for your perspective on the gyroscope stuff. But for flyby; "...inaccuracies in changing from one coordinate system to another." is not a likely candidate considering the number of different people who've looked at it and what they do. There may be a mundane explanation, but that's not likely to be it. Is that just a guess or do you know of something publised aboutthat?

Comment: The idea about inaccuracies in changing coordinate systems is one that was suggested by Viktor Toth in a PIRSA talk on this subject. You should be able to find the talk online if you're interested. There are competent relativists like Toth and Iorio who have been working on the Pioneer anomaly and flyby anomalies for a long time, and they do not believe there is new physics. Switching between coordinate systems in this context does not mean anything as simple as freshman exercises in analytic geometry. It's complicated and depends on a lot of data, which contain random and systematic errors.

Comment: @BenCrowell okay, thanks for the reply, I'll go read some more based on that. I just didn't want future readers to come and think they'd seen a knowledgable person imply 'NASA can't do coordinate transforms properly', at least without some additional context.

Comment: @BenCrowell I don't mean to beleaguer the issue. Only thing I found re Flyby Anomaly and Toth is from 2009 and yes it does talk about coordinate systems. https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4184 However the paper I'm citing is from 2015 http://issfd.org/2015/files/downloads/papers/153_Jouannic.pdf and probably uses a much more seamlessly integrated and thorough analysis that what Toth was talking (complaining) about. "Iorio [8] investigated general relativity as a possible cause. However, this was discarded since its effect (magnitude 10−5 mm/s) is many orders lower than the anomalous ∆V∞ observed."